# React native list Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am simply trying to do a venues list.

Here is the result of `console.log(this.state.venues)`:

```
Array [
    Object {
        "key": "5b0ac89e***",
        "venuename": "Venue1",
    },
    Object {
        "key": "557d70asd****",
        "venuename": "Venue2",
    },
    Object {
        "key": "58f316ccsa****",
        "venuename": "Venue3",
    },
]
```

I am creating this data by pulling it from fq-api like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    this.state.venues.push({
        venuename: response.data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.name,
        key: response.data.response.groups[0].items[i].venue.id
    });
}
```

And here is my JSX:

```
<View style={styles.list}>
    <FlatList data={[this.state.venues]}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.venuename}</Text>}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key} />
</View>
```

I am receiving **Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop** Error. Everything seems ok to me, I don't understand why it fails. I don't know what is this "key prop", I have it from fetch and tried to use it but I can't proceed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `item.key` always set? `keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}`

Comment: Yes every object have it

Comment: Are you sure it should be `data={[this.state.venues]}`? Because `venues` is already an array, so it sounds like you should have `data={this.state.venues}`.

Comment: You are right, I missed that. Much appreciated! @GhassenLouhaichi

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in your `data` prop.

You're putting a bi-dimensional array to the data prop, so the keyExtractor will try to extract: `[].key (undefined)` instead `item.key`...

I think you're also rendering only one item on the list because of the bidimensional array, I'm correct?

Comment: You are correct, apperantly i was trying to render an array of an array. Removing [] from data prop solved that thanks!